# How can I highlight member variables in Python?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to set up a certain type of syntax highlighting for Python.

I want `self` and `cls` to be highlighted like comments.
I want member variables to be highlighted like functions.

For example, if `normal text` is (white), `comments` are (gray), and `functions` are (red):

```
self._member
```

should be `self`(gray)`.`(white)`_member`(red)

```
self._member.other.method()
```

should be `self`(gray)`.`(white)`_member`(red)`.other.method()`(white)

```
self._method()
```

should be `self`(gray)`._method()`(white)

I tried copying and modifying the syntax for decorators since they seemed similar, but no luck. I also took a [look at the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html), but they were pretty intense. Any idea on how I could do this?

Edit:

I *almost* got it:

```
syn keyword pythonThis   cls self
syn match   pythonMember "\(cls\.\|self\.\)\@<=[A-Za-z_]\+\(\.\| \)"

hi link pythonThis    Comment
hi link pythonMember  Function
```

The only problem with this is that a dot following a member variable is red instead of white (`self._member.other.method()` isn't highlighted *exactly* as specified above). Not a big deal, but it would be nice to know how to ignore multiple groups in a single match (It doesn't seem that you can use `\@<=` multiple times).

Comment: What did you try? What was the expected outcome of each line of what you tried? What failed? What didn't? How?

Answer (score 1):

```
syn keyword pythonThis cls self

syn match pythonChain '\v(^|\W)(cls|self)\zs(\s*\.\s*\h\w*)+' contains=pythonMember
syn match pythonMember '\h\w*' contained

hi link pythonThis Comment
hi link pythonMember Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding, in the modeline, a :hi command for each member in current file.